# How to use Telerik.Reporting.Table control by steps

Tags: telerik, reporting

I know this question might look easy, but there is lack of explanation how to use this control on the Web. I have bound a Telerik.Reporting.Table control to a data-source object, but data are never shown in the control. If explanation is provided how to show data in the table step-by-step. For your information, the data-source object is working well with other controls i.e. TextBox.

Comment: If you need more information i can try to provide more information. On the basic step of using Telerik Reporting.

Answer (score 0):

### 1/. Add a data source to your report.

The Telerik Reporting engine includes data source objects:

- SqlDataSource – Enables you to work with Microsoft SQL Server,
  MySQL, Oracle, OLE DB or ODBC databases.
- CsvDataSource – Enables you to work with CSV data.
- ObjectDataSource - Enables you to work with business objects or other classes and allows you to create reports that display data from the middle-tier.
- EntityDataSource – Enables you to connect to the ADO.NET Entity Framework.
- OpenAccessDataSource - Enables you to connect to Telerik Data Access.
- CubeDataSource – Enables you to retrieve data from an OLAP cube using Microsoft Analysis Services.
- OpenClientDataSource – Enables you to retrieve data from OpenEdge AppServer ABL procedures.

### 2/. A Table.

- Drag the Table Wizard item from the Visual Studio Toolbox to the
  detail section of the report.
- On the Choose Data Source page of the Table Wizard, click the Add New
  Data Source button and select the SqlDataSource Component. On the
  Choose Your Data Connection page of the wizard, select the already
  created data connection and click Next.
- Enter your SQL statement and Finish the DataSource wizard.
- Name your column.
- Click a cell, property expression wizard, Click Field and Voila.